# vpython camera movement: how to walk around a tree?

Tags: vpython

I try to move the camera in a circular path around a couple of objects, with the camera always directing to the center. Simplified, up to now I have the following code (displaying a "tree" with a "small stone" to keep track of the movement):

```
import vpython

stem = vpython.cylinder(pos = vpython.vector(0, -1, 0),
                        axis = vpython.vector(0,4,0), length = 2, radius = 0.2)
crown = vpython.sphere(pos = vpython.vector(0, 1.5, 0), radius=0.5)
stone = vpython.sphere(pos = vpython.vector(1, -1.5, 0), radius=0.1)

sposi = vpython.scene.camera.pos         # Startposition
abst = vpython.mag(sposi)
sollwinkel = 95
ziel_x = abst * vpython.cos(sollwinkel)
ziel_y = abst * vpython.sin(sollwinkel)
d_x = ziel_x / 100.0
d_y = ziel_y / 100.0
calc_x = 0

while True:
    vpython.rate(20)
    while calc_x < d_x:
        calc_x = calc_x + d_x
        vpython.scene.camera.pos = vpython.vector(sposi.x + d_x, sposi.y + d_y, sposi.z)
        #vpython.scene.camera.axis = vpython.vector(sposi.x - d_x, sposi.y - d_y, -sposi.z)
        vpython.sleep(0.1)
```

1. I got some movement, but not circular around the center.
2. And the camera axis probably has to be defined in another way, but I can't figure out, how. Actually, it jumps too near to the tree?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0):

The initial camera position is <0, 0, 1.73205>, and sposi is <0.012647, 0.0118344, 1.73205>,
so naturally you don't see any change. Not sure what you're trying to do. I do recommend posting such questions to the VPython forum at

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users